# PHP string split regular

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-split

Regular exp = (Digits)*(A|B|DF|XY)+(Digits)+

I'm confused about this pattern really
I want to separate this string in PHP, someone can help me
My input maybe something like this

1. A1234
2. B         1239
3. 1A123
4. 12A123
5. 1A    1234
6. 12 A 123
7. 1234 B 123456789
8. 12                 XY             1234567890

and convert to this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => XY
    [2] => 1234567890
)

<?php
$input = "12    XY      123456789";
print_r(preg_split('/\d*[(A|B|DF|XY)+\d+]+/', $input, 3));
//print_r(preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $input, 3));
//print_r(preg_split('/\d*[\s,](A|B)+[\s,]\d+/', $input, 3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and capture the numbers, letters, and numbers:

```
$input = "12    XY      123456789";
if (preg_match('/^(?:(\d+)\s*)?(A|B|DF|XY)(?:\s*(\d+))?$/', $input, $matches)){
    array_shift($matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/EpnIB) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2iQjI6/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(\d+)\s*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 1: any or more digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(A|B|DF|XY)` - Group 2: `A`, `B`, `DF` or `XY`
- `(?:\s*(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 3: any or more digits
- `$` - end of string.